# one to many relation from a map in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am a newbie in scala. How do I write this function getFilledOrder() so that it passes the assert test:

```
case class Order(id:String, total:Double, lineItem:Seq[LineItem])
case class LineItem(id:String, productId:String)


val order = Order("1", 10.0, Nil)
val orderLineItemMap = Map(order->List(LineItem("1", "prod1"),LineItem("2", "prod2")))
val filledOrder = getFilledOrder(orderLineItemMap)
assert(filledOrder ==  Order("1", 10.0, List(LineItem("1", "prod1"),LineItem("2", "prod2"))))
```

I am trying to write something like this:

```
def getFilledOrder(orderLineItemMap : Map[Order, List[LineItem]]):Order = { 
    orderLineItemMap.keys.foreach(order=> { 
      val filledOrder = Order(order.id, order.total, orderLineItemMap.get(order).get)
      println(filledOrder)
    })

}
```

This doesn't compile as the function is not returning an Order. How do I get the filledOrder out of the foreach loop. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example is on so particular a case than it is difficult to know what you want your function to do in general. Suppose there are two keys in the map. What should the id and total of the (single) resulting order be?

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clear that the map will always have only one order object key.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are dealing with immutable stuff -- and, in Scala, you usually are, `foreach` is the wrong thing to do. With immutable data, you can use it for output, but nothing else.

This returns all orders contained in the map. Your code assumes the map contains only one order, which means passing a map at all is silly.

```
def getFilledOrder(orderLineMap: Map[Order, LineItem]) = orderLineItemMap.map { 
  case (order, lineItem) => order.copy(lineItem = lineItem) 
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much. The only change I had to do was change the assert method to filledOrder.head as the new method is retuning an Iterable[Order]

Answer (score 0):

Your initial problem is that you need to make your block return a `filledOrder`, which you do by making the last expression `filledOrder`, i.e., after the call to `println`.

The other problem is that `foreach` discards its result. Try `map` instead:

```
scala> val orderLineItemMap = Map("foo"->"bar", "baz"->"bat")
orderLineItemMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] =    Map(foo -> bar, baz -> bat)

scala> orderLineItemMap.keys.map(order => {
 |   val filledOrder = order.reverse
 |   println(filledOrder)
 |   filledOrder
 | })
oof
zab
res1: Iterable[String] = Set(oof, zab)
```

Comment: foreach discards the result of its function argument and returns unit. It won't work.

Comment: That doesn't work. Still the same error. I suppose I shouldn't be using foreach here?

Comment: Probably not. You can do a return from inside the foreach, but that certainly not what you should do.

Comment: Exactly. When you write an explicit return, it will realize this on the bytecode layer with throwing an exception, that is catched outside the foreach and then the value is returned. This is definitely not the way to go ;-).

Comment: Updated answer to take the `foreach` problem into account

Comment: Sorry, this will return an Iterable[String]. I want an order object filled with the LineItems. The rest of the order detail should remain the same.

Comment: @Anjan It will return whatever `filledOrder` is: I used a String as a demonstration. If your call to `Order(order.id, order.total, orderLineItemMap.get(order).get)` returns the Order object filled with LineItems, you should get what you need

Comment: @LarryOBrien Are you sure? The map is returning only a Iterable[String] inside a function

Comment: @AnjanPathak The map returns an `Iterable[filledOrder.class]` -- my example code makes filledOrder a `String` but if in your code you use your original `val filledOrder = Order(order.id, order.total, orderLineItemMap.get(order).get)` you will get an `Iterable[Order]`, which is what I think you want, right?